# how to make a snippet for .npmrc in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

how to make a  snippet for .npmrc in vscode?

Comment: what is in `.npmrc`

Comment: such as `registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com`

Comment: that is the only line

Comment: what's the problem? you don't know how to make a snippet? You don't know how to scope the snippet to files with that extension? (I wouldn't be surprised- I'll be you need to use an extension to register a language mode for that filename extension)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot scope a snippet to a file or a file extension, as an alternative you can make a keybinding where you can scope to file extensions.  In your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",

  "when": "editorTextFocus && (resourceExtname =~ /\\.npmrc/ || resourceFilename =~ /(\\.npmrc)/)",

  "args": {
    "snippet": "registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com"
  }
}
```

This works for both `.npmrc` and `xxxx.npmrc` files.

Since in your case you don't make use of any snippet functionality you could simply use:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "type",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && (resourceExtname =~ /\\.npmrc/ || resourceFilename =~ /(\\.npmrc)/)",
  "args": {
    "text": "registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com"
  }
}
```